# Increase dialogue font size?

Tags: x-rebirth

I'm playing X Rebirth, but I find the dialogue and mission text size too small to read without squinting and hunching towards my computer monitor.

I've looked in the game options but can find anything relating to interface sizes. Here's an example highlighting the area I'm having difficulty with.

[image: Red freehand circle]

Is there a way to increase the text size in the game, particularly in the dialogue choices/menus?

Comment: From what I've been reading on the forums, the text should be comfortably sized if you're running a 720p resolution. But I assume that's not an acceptable solution for... anyone who enjoys HD?

Comment: @Flater so surprising that there woudl be an issue with this game :D

Comment: I gave the game another shot a few weeks ago. I was hoping to see improvements. Some of the controller buttons can't be changed individually. Whatever you set "increase throttle" to, also gets bound to "pitch up/down". Making the game literally unplayable. And this is after the 2.0 major release. So I'm now done with Egosoft, this is simply unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option for it, but it will likely be fixed by modders fairly quickly. There are already several HUD and UI mods available, just not one that fixes this resolution scaling problem yet.